# Help me to solve math homework on logarithmic

Tags: logarithms

How to solve this math home work? Please help..

What is the value of $\log \left(\dfrac{i\pi}{2}\right)$ ?

I got to know the answer is "$\dfrac{i\pi}{2}$", but don't know how to solve it. Please help me.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: How do you know the answer? Note that $e^{i \pi/2} = i$ rather than $i \pi/2$

Comment: Are you asking about $\log(i)$ or $\log( \pi i / 2)$?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

For $z\in\Bbb C^*$ we have

$$\ln z=\ln|z|+i\arg z$$

Comment: What does $\mathbb{C^*}$ denote (as opposed just to $\mathbb{C}$)?

Comment: $\mathbb{C}^* = \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$

Answer (score 0):

Using this

$log z=log|z|+iarg(z)$

you should be able to get $|i\pi/2|=\pi/2$ and $arg(i\pi/2)=\pi/2$ thus, $log(i\pi/2)=log(\pi/2)+i(\pi/2+2n\pi)$, $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.